# Inline editing in tds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, editing

I have the following code to enable inline editing of td cells:

```
$('.edit_td').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    resetEditedCells(); 
    $(this).addClass('active').html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
});

function resetEditedCells() {
        $('.edit_td.active').html(function() {
        return $(this).find('input').val();
    });
}

$(document).click(function() {
    if($('.edit_td').hasClass('active')) {
        var fisk = $('.active input[type=text]').val();
        $('.edit_td').find('input').hide().html(fisk);
    }
});
```

I have two problems:

1. When the TD has transformed to an input field, I can't write a new text in it. I cant edit the text.
2. When I click outside the table, I want the input field to transform back to the td with its original text value, but it does not do that with my code above. The input field is removed, but the text is also removed/hidden. I only want the input to disappear.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: please set up a working fiddle

Comment: @BeNdErR: I don't understand how to use fiddle. :/

Comment: see how here:http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html

Comment: @BeNdErR: Here you have: http://jsfiddle.net/Ewmh5/3/ Try to edit the value in the input field and click outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of what you wanted.

```js
const $edits = $('.edit_td');

$edits.on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    const $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
      $this.addClass('active');
      const val = $this.html();
      console.log(val);
      $this.html(`<input type="text" value="${val}"/>`);
    }
});

function removeActive() {
  $edits.each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
      const val = $this.find('input').val();
      $this.empty();
      $this.html(val);
      $this.removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

$(document).on('click', removeActive);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_td">Test 123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_td">Test 456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="edit_td">Test 789</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the $(this).empty(); for?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hide/show the td/input box instead of changing the html, that will save you from a lot of trouble afterwards.